# css rotation using webkit-animation

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a rotation effect with:

```
#outer {
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    left:0.3%;
    top:0.2%;
    -webkit-animation: rotation 30s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
```

But it wobbles. I'm not sure if it's a CSS issue of just the outer ring isn't a "perfect" circle. Why does it do this?

Outer circle: [image]

You can see a demo [here](http://cssdesk.com/hnRxF).

Comment: The problem is that it does not rotate in a "perfect" circle. If You change -webkit-animation: rotation 30s , to something faster, lets say 5-10 seconds, the difference will be more noticeable.

Comment: Oh, maybe your image is lopsided.

Comment: You think so? I actually thought the same and its not me that made the logo i'm just making the animation. So i guess i'm right insisting that it's a logo issue :P

Comment: I am pretty sure, the reason is because your http://i.imgur.com/LbXvgbp.png or your http://i.imgur.com/V1l3IR5.png are not perfect circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it appears to bob up and down is because your image is lopsided. You can test it with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f758q/).

```
<div></div>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/LbXvgbp.png" width="400" />
<style>
    * { position: absolute }
    div {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #000;
    }
</style>
```

It appears to be elliptical - more wide than tall.

Answer (score 1):

You have `-webkit-` prefixes for animation and keyframes but for other browsers you need the non-prefixed properties, too (`-moz-` and `-ms-` aren't needed for these):

```
#outer {
  -webkit-animation: rotation 30s infinite linear;
  animation: rotation 30s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
}
@keyframes rotation {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to   { transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me... what browser are you using? If it's not webkit you won't see anything without providing the proper vendor prefixes. This is how i usually write transforms

```
-webkit-transform:;
-moz-transform:;
-ms-transform:;
transform:;
```

Comment: This very well could be an answer. I'm sorry, but why do you think you can help stack overflow semantics by polluting this persons thread... just like you are making me do now. Post an answer or non OFF TOPIC comment and everything will be great!

Comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements"

Comment: "But i am not sure if its a css issue of just the outer ring is a "perfect" circle. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance."

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

The @keyframes rule is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, and Opera.

Safari and Chrome support an alternative, the @-webkit-keyframes rule.

Note: The @keyframes rule is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

You should provide rules with and without the -webkit- to support all the current browsers.

```
@keyframes rotation {
from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)